# Need values from every checked data table into a child component in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, datatable

I have to write 1 up to 3 Elements in a child component by checking the Checkbox, i have to handle this for comparing the data on next page.
But the value from selected checkbox is only a object. How could is show the values ob the data table. 
It shoud only show if i checked the box.

[Working draft](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t37dy2)

Answer (score 0):

Push the selected element to an array and then display the array wherever you need to display it. For example:

```
// build the array
private selectRow($event, dataSource) {
 // console.log($event.checked);
  if ($event.checked) {
    // push to an array
    this.arrayOfElements.push(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Then in the template do:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of arrayOfElements">{{element.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the solution I'm looking for.
By select an item push into array and by deselect it splice it again. 
But i have only an object and have to show the data like name or ID or smth like that.

Comment: maybe you can try to adapt what I have added up? like add an `else` condition that will splice your array? Also the template part down does exactly "have to show the data like name or ID or smth like that". Just do something like {{element.id}} or {{element.name}}